# return the value from a promise/ajax call with jquery

Tags: jquery, requirejs, promise, deferred

`var viewmodel = service.createCustomer();` is the way I call the requirejs module.

How do I have to create a deferred object that my createCustomer returns the CreateCustomerViewModel which is created inside the service call?

```
define(['viewmodels/CreateCustomerViewModel'],function (CreateCustomerViewModel) {

    function createCustomer() {
        $.getJSON('Customer/Create')
         .done(function (response) {
             return new CreateCustomerViewModel(response);
         })
         .fail(function (error) {
             alert(error);
         });
    }   

    return {        
        createCustomer: createCustomer        
    };
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You must use `.then()` instead of `.done()` to modify the payload.
2. You should let your `createCustomer` method return the modified payload.

Your module definition becomes:

```
function createCustomer() {
    return $.getJSON('Customer/Create')
        .then(function (response) {
            return new CreateCustomerViewModel(response);
        });
}

return {
    createCustomer: createCustomer
};
```

Use as:

```
customerCreator.createCustomer()
    .done(function (model) {
        // yay! let's use this model
    })
    .fail(function () {
        console.error("Cannot create customer");
    });
```

You should also move the `.fail()` handling outside, as high up in the application as possible, so that the wording in your error message can have a more accurate context.

P.S. As a nitpick, shouldn't you be using a POST request instead of a GET to create an entity?

Comment: 2 things: I want to get the return value via var viewmodel = service.createCustomer() and the .done .fail should be within the service because they just can be service errors. The viewmodel does not know that. Furtheremore its a GET request because I do not post data I retrieve data for the formular to display then later I do a post ;-)

Comment: Since `$.getJSON` will be async, you cannot do `viewmodel = service.createCustomer()`. You have to use either a classic callback or a Promise (better).

Comment: For those using jQuery < 1.8 use `pipe` instead of `then`. I wasted several hours dealing with this.